# well under way/fully under way

Tags: word-choice, difference

The party was well under way when we arrived.
The party was fully under way when we arrived.

What is the difference between "well under way" and "fully under way"?

Comment: They seem the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Well under way" is generally used after something is started and a good amount of the started thing has been done.

while

"Fully under way" is generally used to indicate that the staring of something is complete, but it makes no statement about how much of the thing has been done.

To provide an example, a group doesn't start walking all at once, a few people start walking, and the rest of the group eventually follows.  So when the whole group is finally walking it is "fully under way".

Now let's say the group needs to walk to the park.  After it has moved a good distance from its starting spot, it is "well under way."